# Extra Frame in matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimate

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, random, matplotlib-animation

I am exploring live graphs with matplotlib animations. Currently, I'm just adding a random integer to an array, and having my plot update based on the new number. The issue is that I seem to be getting an extra value drawn to the plot.

I have the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

xs = []
ys = []

def animate(i, xs, ys):
    
    x = i + 1
    y = random.randint(1, 50)
    
    print '{}: {}, {}'.format(i, x, y)
    
    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(y)
            
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)
        
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                              animate,
                              frames = 10,
                              fargs = (xs, ys),
                              repeat = False)
plt.show()
```

I only want 10 values to be drawn, so I set `frames = 10` in the `FuncAnimate` call. However, the print statement is outputting an 11th value:

[image: Plot Result]

[image: Print Statement Output]

So it's clear that 11 frames are being generated, rather than 10.  Looking at the documenation for [FuncAnimate](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation), I can't see a reason why this would be happening.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it is not the most elegant way to solve it, but you could use a flag as a workaround in order to avoid the run of the animation in the very first loop:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

xs = []
ys = []

flag = 0
def animate(i, xs, ys):

    global flag

    if i == 0 and flag == 0:
        flag = 1
        return

    if flag == 1:
        x = i + 1
        y = random.randint(1, 50)

        print '{}: {}, {}'.format(i, x, y)

        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)

        ax1.clear()
        ax1.plot(xs, ys)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                              animate,
                              frames = 10,
                              fargs = (xs, ys),
                              repeat = False)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
0: 1, 37
1: 2, 2
2: 3, 46
3: 4, 39
4: 5, 30
5: 6, 47
6: 7, 16
7: 8, 3
8: 9, 3
9: 10, 49
```

Plot:

[image]

---

**EDIT**:
I have done some research.
This behavior is due to the fact you (and I) do not specified the `init_func` parameter of the `FuncAnimation`. As you can read from the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation):

> `init_func` : callable, optional A function used to draw a clear
> frame. If not given, the results of drawing from the first item in the
> frames sequence will be used. This function will be called once before
> the first frame.   The required signature is:
>
> `def init_func() -> iterable_of_artists`
>
> If `blit == True`, *init_func* must return an iterable of artists to
> be re-drawn. This information is used by the blitting algorithm to
> determine which parts of the figure have to be updated. The return
> value is unused if `blit == False` and may be omitted in that case.

If you do not specify the `init_func`, the first frame is repeated (to be used as a initialization frame).
That said, I think the most proper way to avoid the repetition is to call a `init` function where you do not plot anything:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

xs = []
ys = []

def init():
    ax1.clear()

def animate(i, xs, ys):
    x = i + 1
    y = random.randint(1, 50)

    print '{}: {}, {}'.format(i, x, y)

    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(y)

    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig = fig,
                              func = animate,
                              init_func = init,
                              frames = 10,
                              fargs = (xs, ys),
                              repeat = False)

plt.show()
```

Output:

```
0: 1, 12
1: 2, 25
2: 3, 20
3: 4, 49
4: 5, 49
5: 6, 28
6: 7, 26
7: 8, 49
8: 9, 10
9: 10, 2
```

Animation:

[image]

Comment: This seems like a solid workaround. Is this typical behavior, though? And if so, is there a reason for it?

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for the instruction!